# Python Pandas adding a column where the value is across other rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use multiple rows in the evaluation of a new column on a pandas dataframe. For a little background lets say that I have rows where data has been aggregated and I need to now how my current row compares to that row. For example

| Gender | Name | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M | James | 125 |
| M | Jack | 157 |
| M | **AGG* | 282 |
| F | Sue | 130 |
| F | **AGG* | 130 |

Where *AGG is a special value meaning that row is an aggregate row.
What I would like to do is find what percent of the *agg row each other row is? So the *AGG row is always 1.0 or 100% of itself. What I do is select off the *AGG rows and then add a new column with the agg value back to the main frame before the operation.
The agg frame looks like this.
| Gender | Name | weight | weight_summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | James | 125 | 282 |
| M | Jack | 157 |  282 |
| M | **AGG* | 282 | 282 |
| F | Sue | 130 | 130|
| F | **AGG* | 130 | 130 |

Then I do the operation and drop the extra column so that the final frame looks like this.

| Gender | Name | weight | weight % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | James | 125 | 0.4432624 |
| M | Jack | 157 | 0.5567375 |
| M | **AGG* | 282 | 1.0 |
| F | Sue | 130 | 1.0 |
| F | **AGG* | 130 | 1.0 |

Currently I am doing this the long way which is identifying the *AGG rows then renaming weight and merging it back on the original dataframe.

```
    agg_rows = self.data_frame.query('Name == "*AGG"')['Gender', 'Weight']
    agg_name = 'weight_summary'
    agg_rows.rename({'weight': agg_name }, axis=1, inplace=True)
    on_cols = ['Gender']
    df = df.merge(agg_rows, how='left', on=on_cols)
    df['weight_percent'] = df['weight'].div(df[agg_name])
    df.drop(agg_name, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

My actual code is a little more robust as its dynamic but I think this is enough to get the point across.
This gives me the desired output but doesnt give me a warm and fuzzy feeling. Is there a better way perhaps with masks or without having to add the temporary column on? Any advice is much appreciated even if its just confirming that my approach is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to mask `*AGG` rows to compute the sum for each group then restore them:

```
df['weight %'] = (df['weight'] / df.mask(df['Name'] == '*AGG')
                                   .groupby('Gender')['weight']
                                   .transform('sum')
                                   .fillna(df['weight']))
```

Output:

| Gender | Name | weight | weight % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | James | 125 | 0.443262 |
| M | Jack | 157 | 0.556738 |
| M | *AGG | 282 | 1 |
| F | Sue | 130 | 1 |
| F | *AGG | 130 | 1 |

Comment: Hey Corralien Thanks so much for the response. My follow up question is what if I didnt know what the *agg row function was Currently we assume SUM but what if it could be any statistic (mean, max, min, sum, etc.) could you still do something similar to this if we couldnt re-compute the sum becuase we dont know what the function is or at that point would my approach be the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try groupby combined with a unanimous function

print(df)

```
   Gender   Name  weight
0      M  James     125
1      M   Jack     157
2      F    Sue     130

df['weight%'] = df.groupby('Gender')['weight'].apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())



   Gender   Name  weight   weight%
0      M  James     125  0.443262
1      M   Jack     157  0.556738
2      F    Sue     130  1.000000
```